TypeError: isAddressable is not a function
before i start with question i looked at this answers first and second,but nothing helped. I am writhing some unit tests for my smart contracts using hardhat and keep getting error  TypeError: isAddressable is not a function.I tried answers from that posts but could not managed make it to work.I tried with upgrading ethers,hardhat-chai-matchers and rest of the libraries but nothing, also tried with downgrading also nothing..
This is mine unit test
    const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

describe('CDFiSubscription', function () {
    let cdfiSubscription;
    let mockUSDT;
    let mockUSDC;
    let mockCDFi;
    let chainId;
    let priceFeedAddress;
    let deployer;
    let addr1;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        const [deployer, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();

        this.deployer = deployer;
        const MockToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('MockToken');
        mockUSDT = await MockToken.deploy("USDT", "USDT", ethers.utils.parseEther('1000000'));
        mockUSDC = await MockToken.deploy("USDC", "USDC", ethers.utils.parseEther('1000000'));
        mockCDFi = await MockToken.deploy("CDFi", "CFi", ethers.utils.parseEther('1000000'));

        const CDFiSubscription = await ethers.getContractFactory('CDFiSubscription');


        cdfiSubscription = await CDFiSubscription.deploy(
            mockUSDT.address,
            mockUSDC.address,
            mockCDFi.address,
            deployer.address,
            'CDFiSubscription',
            'CDS'
        );

        await cdfiSubscription.deployed();

        chainId = await ethers.provider.getNetwork().then((network) => network.chainId);
        priceFeedAddress = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'; // Chainlink Aggregator address for ETH/USD on localhost (31337)

    });

    it('should update Chainlink price feed address by owner', async function () {

        await cdfiSubscription.connect(this.deployer).updateChainlinkPriceFeed(chainId, priceFeedAddress);

        const updatedPriceFeedAddress = await cdfiSubscription.priceFeedAddresses(chainId);
        expect(updatedPriceFeedAddress).to.equal(priceFeedAddress);

        const txReceipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(tx.hash);
        const event = txReceipt.events.find((event) => event.event === 'PriceFeedChanged');
        expect(event.args.chainId).to.equal(chainId);
        expect(event.args.priceFeedAddress).to.equal(priceFeedAddress);
    });

    it('should revert if non-owner tries to update Chainlink price feed address', async function () {
        const hacker = addr1;

        await expect(cdfiSubscription.connect(hacker).updateChainlinkPriceFeed(chainId, '0xSomeOtherAddress')).to.be.revertedWith(
            'Ownable: caller is not the owner'
        );
    });



});

and this is my package,json and hardhat.config.ts files
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.6",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.5",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition": "^0.15.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers": "^0.15.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core": "^0.15.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.2",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.5.0",
    "chai": "^4.4.1",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.9",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^10.5.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3"
  }
}

and
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.20",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    localhost: {
      url: "http://localhost:8545",
    },
  },
};

export default config;

